# wix heat and linker

Tags: parameters, linker, wix, heat

I'm using Heat (3.10) to harvest all the files of my app.

Heat command:

`<HeatDirectory NoLogo="True" ToolPath="$(WixToolPath)" TreatWarningsAsErrors="False" GenerateGuidsNow="True" OutputFile="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\FilesForSetup.wxs" Directory="$(OutDir)\..\Server" ComponentGroupName="FilesForSetup" DirectoryRefId="ServerFolder" SuppressFragments="True" SuppressUniqueIds="False" SuppressCom="True" SuppressRootDirectory="True" SuppressRegistry="True" RunAsSeparateProcess="True" />`

Linker Command:

`-b "$(OutDir)\..\Server"`

When I ran the command with OutputPath instead of OutDir it worked but if I change it to OutDir which is received from the Command Line it fails. **How can I achieve that?**

Answer (score 0):

WiX requires that `OutDir` already has a trailing backslash, so if you set it from the commandline that could cause it to fail.

If instead you set `OutputPath` then it will set OutDir to match (appending the backslash if needed). It's expected that both will have the same value, but the backslash is only critical on `OutDir`.